# I cant show the multiple images in each function of jquery

Tags: jquery

I have group_concat the images by dates and which are send to ajax success

```
var r = res[index].PostImage.split(',');
```

they are spilted..
And i want them to show in div like this..

```
$('.tab-pane').html(
  $('.tab-pane').html() + '<div>Here is date..</div><div class="imgs">'+
    $.each(r, function(rf) {
      one.append('<img src="posts/'+r[rf]+'" alt=""><br/>');
    }) +'</div>'
)
```

This gives the images without img tag ..which cannot be displayed..
Thanks..

Comment: Please don't spam other tags, there's no `php` or `sql` in your question

Comment: r[rf] has to be rf

Comment: What do you mean by "this gives the images without the img tag"?  Why can't it be displayed?  What specifically is wrong?

Comment: so can you post your response that you are getting , the answer that you are looking is you need to append the img tags with img src after the .tab-pane class

Comment: @David the images wont be displayed because of img tag..

Comment: You cannot concatenate from `$.each()` in the manner you're attempting. What is `one` a reference to? Also, what is your expected output?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan to this  var one = $('#post_image');

Comment: So are you trying to include the `<img />` elements within the HTML you set inside `.tab-pane`, or append them to `#post_image`?

Comment: @Sachin: Why can't they?  Stop making this a *guessing game* and provide information about the problem.  When you debug your code, where specifically does it fail?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , yes..

Comment: @David they are displayed like this <div class="imgs">1.jpg, 2.jpg</div>

Comment: @Sachin I asked you to choose which of the two possibilities you're trying to create and you reply 'yes'. You are giving us absolutely useless information here. This question deserves its impending closure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `each` you can try `map` just like below.

```
var images = ['img1.png', 'img2.png']; 

function render() {
   $('.tab-pane').html(
    '<div>Here is date..</div><div class="imgs">'+
       images.map(function(src, index) {
        return '<img src="posts/'+src+'" alt=""><br/>';
    })
    +'</div>')
}
```